# Unable to get form's panel x and y coordinates and to set them from a cookie on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a panel inside:

```
<form id="form" action="/accent/login/enter/">
    <div draggable="true" id="panel" title="">
    ...
```

The panel is `draggable` and `resizable` and has two events:

```
$('#panel').bind("resize",function(event){
               saveform();
           })
           .bind("drag",function(event){
               saveform();
           });
```

The function `saveform` is supposed to save form's panel `width` and `height` and besides x and y coordinates. It saves it in a cookie. I want this behaviour, so that when a user refreshes a page, then the form's panel is positioned and aligned according to those properties saved in a cookie. The first problem I face is that x and y coordinates are recalculated only once, that is when a user drags and drop the form for the first time. As for height and width they are recalculated correctly. And the second problem I face is that I'm unable to set x and y coordinates of a form - I do not know whether the method I use is appropriate or not. So, my `saveform` function looks like this:

```
var saveform = function(){
    var pos = $('#form:first').offset(), // recalculated only once
    height = $('#panel').height(), // it is saved ok
    width = $('#panel').width(), // it's ok too
    data = {top:Math.round(pos.top),left:Math.round(pos.left),
        height:Math.round(height),width:Math.round(width)};
    $.cookie('form',data);
}
```

And this is the method I use to set x and y coordinates of the panel:

```
var data = $.cookie('form');
$('#panel').position({
        of:$('#body'),
        my:'left top',
        at:'left top',
        offset:data.left + " " + data.top
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution. Now, my `saveform` function looks like this:

```
var saveform = function(){
    var pos = $('div.panel').offset(), //I added class="panel" to main div
    height = $('#panel').height(),
    width = $('#panel').width();
    $.cookie('form',{top:pos.top,left:pos.left,
        height:height,width:width});
}
```

And I set panel's x and y coordinated like this:

```
var data = $.cookie('form');
$('#panel').height(data.height).width(data.width)
               .offset({top:data.top,left:data.left});
```

So, the main trick was to apply `offset` method in appropriate manner.